# Does PLINQ really not preserve order?

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

At [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677(v=vs.110).aspx) it is said that PLINQ does not preserve order. I wanted to demonstrate it in my project but I have a problem, that is preserves order all the time. I have a collection `List<Tuple<int, int>> table` and these are my queries:

```
var linqQuery = table
            .Where(n => Enumerable.Range(2, (int) Math.Sqrt(n.Item1)).All(i => n.Item1 % i > 0))
            .Take(10)
            .ToList();

var plinqQuery = table
            .AsParallel()
            .Where(n => Enumerable.Range(2, (int) Math.Sqrt(n.Item1)).All(i => n.Item1 % i > 0))
            .Take(10)
            .ToList();
```

They both produce the same ordered result even when I don't use `.AsOrdered()`. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: *"does not preserve order"* is not the same as *"always shuffles the data"*. Try a query which does not process each item with almost the same amount of CPU cycles, or with more data, or with a more involved query.

Comment: It likely depends on how it's being partitioned. MSDN is saying it does not guarantee preserving order, but it isn't saying it will always return a different order, either.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I use it on really big collection of data. Do you have any idea how can I modify the query to get two different results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PLINQ does not guarantee that items will be processed in order. Whether it processes them in order or not depends on a couple of factors.

First of all, it is not known in advance on how many threads the operations will be executed. In small examples, chances are that only one or two threads will be used.

Second, keep in mind that `Task` is not equal to thread. Task is what to do. Thread is the engine which runs it. Task manager chooses which task to put onto which thread. It will not run a new thread just because there are tasks waiting, unless there are unused CPU resources to truly run that thread.

Third, even if there are multiple threads running tasks in parallel, chances are that tasks will complete in the same order in which they have been started.

Conclusion is that PLINQ will not do anything to make tasks run in the same order in which they were initialized, and true order of execution is the result of several factors. Your code should not depend on either outcome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there some way how can I modify the query to get different order with higher propability?

Comment: I don't see how, because that is a separate concern. If order is important, then link the tasks as continuations - that is the way to guarantee that one task will follow another. If only order of results is important, but not the order of processing, then put results into an array, so that each one gets into its fixed slot.

Comment: Another option to sort results is to include an index into source data, and then to include the same index into the resulting object. Then sort the results by the index, and output objects will follow the same sequence as the inputs they came from.

Comment: I just want to demonstrate that it does not preserve order. But when I used Take(1000) instead of just 10 then on some indexes there was difference, so I am happy now

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to showcase it, why not use a simple ForEach vs ForAll with a large Enumerable set?

For instance:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO.MacakM.Answer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Using LINQ...");
            range.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

            Console.WriteLine("Using PLINQ...");
            range.AsParallel().ForAll(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

You will probably have the order scrambled in the last one. [Test it in .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/chkTtf)

Comment: I would rather use `Where` instead of `ForEach`

Comment: OK, that was not clear :) but I think that you got it solved already by using a large take, so there you go

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
   .AsOrdered()
```

example:

```
   list.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
```

Notice that this can impact performance